# Source of the saying

Tags: scripture

What is the source of this Hindu saying-

> "There are hundreds of paths up the mountain, all leading to the same place, so it doesn't matter which path you take. The only person wasting time is the one who runs around the mountain, telling everyone that his or her path is wrong."

Comment: _Book of Apocrypha_?

Answer (score 1):

It is very similar to the *Siva Mahimnah-stotra* verse 7 (As quoted by Swami Vivekananda, appears in both vol 1 and 3 - https://advaitaashrama.org/cw/):

> As the different streams having their sources in different places all mingle their water in the sea, so, O Lord, the different paths which men take through different tendencies, various though they appear, crooked or straight, all lead to Thee.